# Basic PHP script that records text based on link

Tags: java, php

I am originally a java programmer but I need a very basic PHP script that will record the text given from the link to a .txt file(or an alternative) .

Such as

In java

```
String url = http://www.mywebsite.com/recorder.php?=

String stringToRecord = blablabla

String websitetovisit = url + stringToRecord
```

Then I'd just make the java application inquire that link and the script would add the string after ?= in a txt file.

But I have literally no experience in PHP.

How do I accomplish this? I have tried reading some PHP tutorials but I still don't have the slightest idea about this.

EDIT:

Let's say that there's the website www.mywebsite.com and there's a file in it, recorder.php

What recorder.php does is gets the string IN the link after the ?= and pastes it in a local .txt file.

So basically

www.mywebsite.com/recorder.php?=this_is_a_test

Would parse

this_is_a_test

into a local .txt file.

This is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_readfile.asp is this what you mean?

Comment: No, vice versa. I'm trying to get the text from the URL and parse it into a .txt file.

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292369/parse-web-page-content-using-php?

Comment: You mean you want to download the webpage when given a URL?

Comment: @bas&MrLore no. I will edit the original post to give you clearer instructions.

Comment: @bas NO! [DON'T USE W3SCHOOLS!](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the query part of the URL as-is (as it looks in the browser's address bar), then you could use:

```
file_put_contents('query.txt', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/recorder.php?=";

$stringToRecord = "blablabla";

$websitetovisit = url ."". stringToRecord;
$text = file_get_contents($websitetovisit);
file_put_contents('test.txt', $text);
```

**I EDIT CODE**

Comment: I'm not trying to convert java to PHP. I just tried to show what I would do in the java part of this whole idea.

Comment: @joedacoolguy Sorry, I didn't understand you. Now I edit the code. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('a.txt', file_get_contents($url));
```

This is how you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the following code and paste it in you recorder.php

```
<?
/*$_GET returns all get parameter as an array.print_r will convert the 
 array to string and file_put_contents will save it to file*/
file_put_contents("text.txt",print_r($_GET,true));
```